# kudan android samples app displays black screen

Tags: android-studio, augmented-reality, kudan

I  have a problem with the kudan sample project in android . I followed the Kudan  Android Sdk tutorial . The project builds with no errors , but when i Run the app on my device it shows a black screen . Anyone know why this happens ? Thanks .

Comment: I don't know for android-studio, but if you're having problems with Kudan in Unity, you could look at this : https://wiki.kudan.eu/Unity_Gotchas.

Comment: with unity everything works fine  .

Comment: because you need proper model for that

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load a 3D model you have to use Kudan AR Toolkit to convert the model to **yourModelname.armodel** archive extension.
And then manually change the archive extension to .jet